# cloudflare and subdomains / redirects

Tags: apache, redirect, dns, cloudflare

I am having some trouble with some but not all my subdomains when using cloudflare.

The apache virtualhost redirects that don't involve ports are all ok... 
eg: 
http://domain.com.au/gallery > http://gallery.domain.com.au works ok and all run through cloudflare (orange cloud) as they should. 

Noting the following: 
1. BIND9 and apache had a working A record / virtualhost redirect prior to connecting via cloudflare
2. CloudFlare cloud for this DNS A record is grey not orange

Where I am having trouble is in the following examples:
http://domain.com.au:767/web > http://subdomain1.domain.com.au 
http://domain.com.au:7979 > http://subdomain2.domain.com.au
The errors I am getting on this when trying connect through a browser are timeout errors. Help / ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The best work around I have found involves:

1. Create a Page Rule with the following:

   - URL Pattern = `http://subdomain2.domain.com.au`
   - Turn on forwarding
   - Destination URL = `http://0.0.0.0:7979` (change 0.0.0.0 to your IP Address)
2. Go back to CloudFlare DNS settings and turn on the orange clouds.

What this seems to do is route traffic through the CloudFlare system and then the Page Rule grabs it and directs it to the pure IP address. It displays a terrible looking URL however it works.